# Здравствуйте. Пробую написать простенькую программу для просмотра траффика на си. Все собирается, но не работает. Помогите разобраться

Tags: c, консоль, сниффер

```
#include <stdio.h>//Пишем как клиент
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define SIO_RCVALL 0x98000001
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE 0x10000

typedef struct IPHeder {
    unsigned char version;
    unsigned char typeserv;
    unsigned short lenght;
    unsigned short id;
    unsigned short flag;
    unsigned char timelive;
    unsigned char protocol;
    unsigned short headersum;
    unsigned int sourceaddr;
    unsigned int destaddr;
    unsigned char data[];
} IPHeader; // Структура для вывода ip заголовка

int main() {
    WSADATA wsd;
    SOCKET s;
    HOSTENT* hst;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    //SOCKADDR_IN saddr;
    IN_ADDR iaddr;
    char name[128];
    int err;

    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsd); // Инициализация винсок

    if (err != 0) { // Проверка инициализации винсок
        printf("WinSock error\n");
        WSAGetLastError();
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("WinSock OK\n");
    }

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP); // Инициализация сокета

    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) { // Проверка сокета
        printf("Socket error", err);
        WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        closesocket(s);
    } else {
        printf("Socket OK\n");
    }


    err = gethostname(name, sizeof(name)); // Имя машины
    if (err) {
        printf("gethostname function failed %d\n", err);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else 
        printf("Host name: %s\n", name);

    hst = gethostbyname(name); // Адрес машины
    err = WSAGetLastError();
    if (err) {
        printf("gethostbyname function failed %d\n", err);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //memcpy(&saddr.sin_addr.s_addr, hst->h_addr_list[1], sizeof(saddr.sin_addr.s_addr)); // Имя хоста копируем в saddr
    ZeroMemory(&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Заполняем поля структуры saddr
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr*)hst->h_addr_list[1])->s_addr;
    
    err = bind(s, (struct sockaddr_in*)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)); // Привязка сокета
    
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR) { // Проверка 
        printf("Bind error\n", err);
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Bind OK\n");
    }

    unsigned long flag = 1;
    char buff[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; // 
    ioctlsocket(s, SIO_RCVALL, &flag);
    IPHeader* header;
    while (1) { 
        err = recv(s, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        if(err == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("Recv error", err);
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        } else {
            header = (IPHeader*)buff;
            iaddr.s_addr = header->sourceaddr;
            printf("Source", inet_ntoa(iaddr));
            iaddr.s_addr = header->destaddr;
            printf("Destaddr", inet_ntoa(iaddr));
        }
    }
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает" ? Не запускается, не видит трафик? Выдаются сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: Здравствуйте, не видит трафик. Ошибок не выводит. Начиная с bind - нет сообщений об ошибке или об удачном срабатывания.

Answer (score 0):

> не видит трафик. Ошибок не выводит

И почему Ваша программа **должна**  видеть чужой трафик? :-) Для такого захвата чужого трафика, необходимо выполнение, как мимнимум, трёх условий:

1. Программу нужно запускать с привилегиями суперпользователя
2. Сокет нужно открывать "сырым". Вот так:

   s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
3. Созданному сокету нужно разрешить работать в воровском режиме. Вот так:

   ioctlsocket(socket, SIO_RCVALL, &RS_Flag);

Короче, настоятельно реколмендую Вам прочитать хотябы вот эту статью:

https://habr.com/ru/post/164901/

Comment: Спасибо, теории не хвает. А если я, хочу отслеживать трафик на своей машине?Посоветуйте пожалуйста что прочесть.

Comment: @Кирилл  "Посоветуйте пожалуйста что прочесть" - Конкретно по этому вопросу я дал ссылку, а если вообще, про сокеты, то тут надо понимать, что сокеты в винде и сокеты в люнихе - это сильно не одно и тоже. Про виндовозные я мало, что знаю, а если про люних, то рекомендую почитать главу 16 в талмуте У. Ричард Стивенс, Стивен А. Раго "UNIX. Профессиональное программирование".